# page getting refresh while using angular js in MVC4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to angular Js, I am using it with MVC application in dot net.There is a simple page containing a textbox to enter value.But as I call this page,the page starts getting refreshed.I dont know where I have gone wrong.Please help me for the same.

My JS

```
appRoot.controller('CreateSubjectController', function ($scope, $location, $resource) {

    usersubject = {};
    $scope.addSubject = function (subject) {
        $scope.subject.subjectname = subject.subjectname;
    }
});
```

My app.js

```
// Main configuration file. Sets up AngularJS module and routes and any other config objects

var appRoot = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ngResource', 'angularStart.services', 'angularStart.directives']);     //Define the main module

appRoot
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view)
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })
            .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/home/contact', controller: 'ContactController' })
            .when('/about', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'AboutController' })
            .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })
            .when('/createSubject', { templateUrl: '/Subject/createSubject', controller: 'CreateSubjectController' })
            .when('/angular', { templateUrl: '/home/angular' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }])
    .controller('RootController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
            $scope.activeViewPath = $location.path();
        });
    }]);
```

My view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "createSubject";
}

<h2>createSubject</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.subjectname" />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn" data-ng-click="addSubject(subject)" value="Save" />
</div>
```

my Master Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>AngularStart1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body data-ng-app="main" data-ng-controller="RootController">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href='#/home'>AngularStart1</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/home'}"><a href='#/home'>Home</a></li>
                        <li data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/demo'}"><a href="#/demo">Demo</a></li>
                        <li data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/angular'}"><a href='#/angular'>Learn Angular</a></li>
                        <li data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/about'}"><a href='#/about'>About</a></li>
                        <li data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/contact'}"><a href='#/contact'>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did u add ng-app and ng-controller directives. ?

Comment: I guess there is no need to use ng-app and ng-controller directives,as I am using app.js given to me by angular js and mvc, it can itself route the data

Comment: I don't think. It should be there in your view, then only angular identifies its scope.

Comment: well I have defined it in body tag in master page,i have now updated my question

Comment: Are your templates actual calls to action methods on ur Home controller in MVC? for exampele (.when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })), is this a call to "home" controller, method "main" ?